# Effects of reaction wheels desaturation on satellite planning

Tags: reaction-wheel, planning

I'm quite new to the space sector and I'm wondering how the desaturation of the reaction wheels can affect the current plan of a satellite.
I'll try to be more clear: what does it happen to the current plan if a desaturation to the RWs is commanded? Can the satellite continue with his plan (so, maybe, performing an imaging task) even if it is necessary to desaturate the RWs?
I'm trying to look for some references in literature, but for now with no success.
Also,I'm pretty curious about how on-board planning should interact with the RWs desaturation. If I assume to have an on-board planning algorithm, could I obtain some benefits by considering the RW desaturation as any other task (e.g. imaging or recharge task)?

Thank everyone that will help me in solving these doubts!

Comment: Under normal operations, possibility of wheel saturation is _predicted before the imaging starts_ and a wheel de-saturation (or wheel speed biasing) is done _before_ the imaging starts.

Comment: You would need to consider more information.  How are you desaturating wheels (torquers, thrusters?)  Do you need to change attitude to put the torquers or thrusters in the right configuration?  How long will the desaturation event last?  Is the imaging a simple click and shoot frame camera or do you have high stability requirements?